# Maven Resource Plugin: Adding a dynamic amount of XML tags

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

currently I am using the Maven Resource plugin in a project in order to set some properties dependent on a specific Maven Build Profile (e.g. database settings for dev / productive environments). This works quite well.

However I want to set some "complex" structure dependent on the specified profile. In a specific Spring XML file I've got the following lines of XML to add some members to a distributed Hazelcast data-structure.

```
 <hz:join>
    <hz:tcp-ip>
          <hz:member>192.168.178.37</hz:member>
    </hz:tcp-ip>
 </hz:join>
```

Depending on a specific Maven Profile and (maybe) with the help of the Maven Resource Plugin, I like to add dynamically more `<hz:member> tags` in this section.

For example: The dev profile has 4 members and the productive 12. I don't want to change this part every time I build a specific profile (and vice-versa).

So is there a possibility to do this via Maven Resource filtering? Or are there any other ideas to dynamically add those member tags depending on Maven profile at build time?